# Double picker view

Tags: iphone, xcode4, uipickerview

Hello im working with a double picker view with images, one side text and the other images, but I cant make it work. Here is the picker components. There are 3 arrays, Array and Array1 content text, and ImagesArray content images. X its a variable that depends on what button you pressed. Thanks.

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView;
{
    return 2;
}

- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:    (NSInteger)component;
{
    if (X == 1) {
       if (component == 0) {

        return [self.Array count];
        }
        if (component == 1)
        {
            return [self.ImagesArray count];    
        }
        }     
    if (X == 2) {

        if (component == 0) {
            return [self.Array1 count];
        }

        if (component == 1) {
            return [self.ImagesArray count];
        }            
        }
    }

- (UIView *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView viewForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component reusingView:(UIView *)view{

    if (component == 1){
        return [self.ImagesArray objectAtIndex:row];
    }
}

- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component;
{
    if (X == 1){
        if (component == 0)
        { 
            return [self.Array objectAtIndex:row];
        }
    }   
    if (X == 2) {
        if (component == 0){
        return [self.Array1 objectAtIndex:row]; 
        }
}
}
```

Comment: Please list your desired behavior and your observed behavior.  Also, please give details on any errors.

Answer (score 2):

Let me point out a few issues with your code.

1. You have a `;` at the end of your `numberOfRows` method before starting the method block. That won't work.
2. You are using capitalized first letters for instance variables - bad idea.
3. You are not using `else` clauses, causing tests to be run when they are no longer necessary.
4. The way you nest your if statements also creates repetitive code.

You are probably not seeing any images, because of what is in your images array. This array, the way you are using it, should contain UIImageViews. However, this would defeat the purpose of reusable views. Rather, you should have an array with images or images names and create the view only if necessary.

```
- (UIView *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView 
            viewForRow:(NSInteger)row
          forComponent:(NSInteger)component 
           reusingView:(UIView *)view{
   if (component!=1) return nil;
   UIImageView *imageView = nil;
   UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:[self.imagesArray objectAtIndex:row]];
   if (view==nil) {
     imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
   }
   else {
      imageView = (UIImageView *)view;
      imageView.image = image;
   }
   view = imageView;
   return view;
}
```

If it still does not work, please be more specific about what is not working.

Comment: I see how you do it, but its a large list of images so I make the image Array in the viewDidLoad. When I run it generate this error Thread 1: Proram received signal: "EXC_BAD_ACCESS". And thanks for your help Mundi.